# Fluid width div with image on right

Tags: css, html

Please take a look at my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gX5r9/

I want the div to be of width 100% in the event the browser is resized however I want the icon image to be to the right of it.

```
 <div class="theDiv">
     <input type="text" /><img src="http://images.ilias.ca/Firefox-32x32.png" />
 </div>


.theDiv input {
 width:100%;
 height 32px;
 border= 1 px solid;
 border-radius: 6px;    
 }

 .theDiv img{
  display: inline;    
 }
```

Comment: My solution not what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
.theDiv input {
   width:100%;
   height 80px;
   border= 1 px solid;
   border-radius: 6px; 
   padding-top:10px;
   padding-bottom:10px;   
   display:block;  
   background-image:url(http://images.ilias.ca/Firefox-32x32.png);  
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:right center;

}
```

About the checking if the window is resized. See this resource [@media](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

**Solution 2**

```
.theDiv {
  height:32px;
  position:relative;
}
.theDiv input {
   width:100%;
   height 32px;
   border= 1 px solid;
   border-radius: 6px;    
}

.theDiv img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:666;
    right:10px;   
}
```

​

Comment: Still doesnt work.  The input div runs into the image.  That is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this using background images: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gX5r9/8/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="theDiv">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

​

**CSS**

```
.theDiv input {
   height:32px;
   border: 1px solid  #999;
   border-radius: 6px;    
   width:100%;
   vertical-align:bottom;
}
.theDiv {
    background:url(http://images.ilias.ca/Firefox-32x32.png) 100% 0% no-repeat;
    padding-right:38px;
    height:40px;
}
```

​